# Google Dialogflow doesn't utilize my changes

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a simple AI chatbot command for my discord bot and it's working out, however, my Dialogflow doesn't seem to utilize any changes that I made like new intents or different responses. it always just returns the text from before the changes or just doesn't return anything at all.

I might be really stupid.

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const axios = require('axios');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

require("dotenv").config();
const projectId = "mydialogprojectid";

console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

const config = require(`../config.json`)

exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
    message.channel.startTyping();

    // A unique identifier for the given session
    const sessionId = uuid.v4();
    console.log(sessionId)

    // Create a new session
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
          text: args.join(' '),
          // The language used by the client (en-US)
          languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
      },
    };

    // Send request and log result
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

    const result = responses[0].queryResult;

    if (result.intent) {
      console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
    }
    console.log(result)
    message.channel.stopTyping();
    return message.channel.send(result.fulfillmentText ? result.fulfillmentText : "Something went wrong, forgive me please! I'm still in beta.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue it works on the Dialogflow console etc but when using it in discord it wouldnt find the intent etc like you described.

At first i thought this was just some cache issue. I will update this if i find a solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30622117)

Comment: @xom9ikk i know im also sorry for this but i wasnt able to comment on his question so this was a little hacky work around.